# WebGL custom shadow mapping shader code not working

Tags: webgl, shader, shadow

I've seen different methods for shadow mapping all around the internet but I've only seen one method for mapping the shadows cast by a point light source, i.e. Cube mapping. Even though I've heard of it I've never seen an actual explanation of it.

I started writing this code before I had heard of cube mapping. My goal with this code was to map the shadow depths from spherical coordinates to a 2D texture.

I've simplified the coloring of the fragments for now in order to better visualize what's happening.

But, basically the models are a sphere of radius 2.0 at coordinates (0.0, 0.0, -5.0) and a hyperboloid of height 1.0 at (0.0, 0.0, -2.0) with the light source at (0.0, 0.0, 8.0).

If I scale(written in the code) the depth values by an inverse factor of less than 9.6 they both appear completely colored as the ambient color. Greater than 9.6 and they slowly become normally textured. I tried to make an example in jsfiddle but I couldn't get textures to work.

The method isn't working all together and I'm lost.

```
<script id="shadow-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    varying float vDepth;

    uniform vec3 uLightLocation;
    uniform mat4 uMMatrix;

    void main(void){
        const float I_PI = 0.318309886183790671537767; //Inverse pi
        vec4 aPos = uMMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0); //The actual position of the vertex
        vec3 position = aPos.xyz - uLightLocation; //The position of the vertex relative to the light source i.e. "the vector"
        float len = length(position);
        float theta = 2.0 * acos(position.y/len) * I_PI - 1.0; //The angle of the vector from the xz plane bound between -1 and 1
        float phi = atan(position.z, position.x) * I_PI; //The angle of the vector on the xz plane bound between -1 and 1

        vDepth = len; //Divided by some scale. The depth of the vertex from the light source
        gl_Position = vec4(phi, theta, len, 1.0);
    }
</script>
<script id="shadow-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying float vDepth;

    void main(void){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vDepth, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //Records the depth in the red channel of the fragment color
    }
</script>
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uMMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
    varying vec4 vPosition;
    varying vec4 aPos;

    void main(void) {
        aPos = uMMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0); //The actual position of the vertex
        vPosition = uMVMatrix * uMMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vTransformedNormal = normalize(uNMatrix * mat3(uMMatrix) * aVertexNormal);
    }
</script>
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
    varying vec4 vPosition;
    varying vec4 aPos;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform sampler2D uShSampler;
    uniform vec3 uLightLocation;
    uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;
    uniform vec4 uLightColor;

    void main(void) {
        const float I_PI = 0.318309886183790671537767;
        vec3 position = aPos.xyz - uLightLocation; //The position of the vertex relative to the light source i.e. "the vector"
        float len = length(position);
        float theta = acos(position.y/len) * I_PI; //The angle of the vector from the xz axis bound between 0 and 1
        float phi = 0.5 + 0.5 * atan(position.z, position.x) * I_PI; //The angle of the vector on the xz axis bound between 0 and 1
        float posDepth = len; //Divided by some scale. The depth of the vertex from the light source
        vec4 shadowMap = texture2D(uShSampler, vec2(phi, theta)); //The color at the texture coordinates of the current vertex
        float shadowDepth = shadowMap.r; //The depth of the vertex closest to the light source
        if (posDepth > shadowDepth){ //Check if this vertex is further away from the light source than the closest vertex
            gl_FragColor = vec4(uAmbientColor, 1.0);
        }
        else{
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        }
    }
</script>
```